# Adding WKInterfaceTimer to SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, watchos

How to add WKInterfaceTimer to SwiftUI ? Anyone who already did it ?
There is no init for WKInterfaceTimer how to do it ?

Comment: I've just filed a report in Feedback Assistant that there should be the ability to initialize a WKInterfaceTimer for use in SwiftUI (FB6565180).

Comment: Did you hear back from the Feedback Assistant?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
Text(date, style: .timer)
```

The style .timer ensures that the text will be updated automatically.

Please note: [This feature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:style:)) has been added to iOS 14 and watchOS 7.